# Programmatically created views in ScrollView

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to add views which are created programmatically into a `ScrollView` and that `ScrollView` is declared in an XML file.  How to achieve this?

```
package com.example.multipleviews;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainView extends Activity {

    LinearLayout main, child;
    ScrollView sc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_view);
        main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello", 0).show();
        view();
    }

    private void view() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        main.removeAllViews();

        sc = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sc);
        sc.removeAllViews();

        child = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin);
        child.removeAllViews();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Button b = new Button(this);
            b.setText("Button "+i);
            b.setId(i);
            child=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lin);
            child.addView(b);

        }
        sc.addView(child);
        main.addView(sc);
        setContentView(main);

    }

}
```

here is my code.....but application does not runs.....

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Add any layout container in `ScrollView`(e.g linear layout )

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/resultContentHolder"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal|top" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</ScrollView>
```

Step 2:Add any custom view in layout container in activity clas for e.g

```
LinearLayout gapH = new LinearLayout(this);
            LayoutParams gapParamsH = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,10);
            gapH.setLayoutParams(gapParamsH);
            resultContentHolder.addView(gapH);
```

Answer (score 0):

firs create a child layout in that you can create your dynamic view.You can refer this [link](http://androidexample.com/Dynamically_Create_View_Elements__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=115&aaid=137) for adding dynamic views.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that you want to use a `ScrollView` for this?  It sounds like you might be better served with a `ListView`.

In case a `ListView` is what you need, [this tutorial on vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)
 is one of the best tutorials I know for how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Find the ScrollView 
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);

// Create a LinearLayout element
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

// Add Buttons
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText("Some text");
linearLayout.addView(button);

// Add the LinearLayout element to the ScrollView
scrollView.addView(linearLayout);
```

[See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369062/how-do-i-add-elements-dynamically-to-a-view-created-with-xml)

Comment: please see updated question i am unable to understand whats wrong