# I'm trying to create Dynamic EditText But getting Error

Tags: java, android, xml

Is there any way to get this thing done. I'm getting input from another activity to create dynamic editText to get input.

```
public class GetNames extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.names);
    LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.lin);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String entered_no = bundle.getString("no_of_persons");

    for (int i = 0; i < (Integer.valueOf(entered_no)); i++) {
        EditText editText = new EditText(GetNames.this);
        editText.setId(editText.generateViewId());
        ll.addView(editText,0);
        editText.setHint(i);
    }
}
```

}

Is there any way to resolve this.

Her is my XML file

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lin"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
```

Here are error messages

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abhishakkrmalviya.perfecthalf/com.abhishakkrmalviya.perfecthalf.GetNames}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
```

Comment: Did my example help you?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not setting layout parameters, That have a look at this example.

```
ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainConstraint);
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

EditText editText = new EditText(GetNames.this);
editText.setId(View.generateViewId());
editText.setHeight(50);
editText.setWidth(50);

layout.addView(view,0);
set.clone(layout);
set.connect(view.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, layout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 60);
set.applyTo(layout);
```

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275152/how-to-programmatically-add-views-and-constraints-to-a-constraintlayout) for more info