# how to add and remove spinner on button click in Android Studio

Tags: android, dynamic, spinner

I want to add and remove spinner on button click but the total no. of spinners should be only 3.

Comment: This is an easy task but the answer depends on what you have already written.  Please read [ask] and then show us what you have tried for that read [mcve].

Comment: One alternative would be to add the `Spinner` to your layout and toggle the Visibility to either `VISIBLE` or `GONE`

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an onClickListener on the button
2. In the onClick method you need to get the UI component which will be the container for the Spinner (f.e. a LinearLayout) with `findViewById`
3. Create the Spinner [new Spinner(this, mode)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#Spinner(android.content.Context,%20int)) (mode is `MODE_DIALOG` or `MODE_DROPDOWN`)
4. Set [SpinnerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html) providing the data for the Spinner with [setAdapter()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)). The type of the adapter depends on the data you want to put there.
5. Add this Spinner in the container by `addView()` ([explore the params in the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)).

You can see an example of adding a view dynamically [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6369062/9274948).

Regarding the requirement of the amount limitation of the Spinners, you could simply track the current amount in a private field of the Activity you are working on. Of course you need to check the current amount before adding a new Spinner.

Removing a spinner is similar to adding one, just call `removeView(View view)` or `removeViewAt(int index)`.

---

If you don't need to fill the Spinners with different data every time, i.e. you are sure that the first Spinner will have f.e. data "cat","dog","fish": You can get the reference to the Spinner and work with its visibility by [setVisibility()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)) setting it to `VISIBLE` `INVISIBLE` or `GONE`.